# Debian 11: setting up L2TP + IPSec - IPSec fails?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, l2tp

I'm trying to configure a new VPN client (L2TP and IPSec) on a very small AWS EC2 system running Debian 11 without a desktop. I've got as far as getting NetworkManager to work, but the VPN connection doesn't start, apparently because of an error to do with IPSec. This is what I did - in one terminal window (IP addresses etc have been changed):

```
root@client# /run/network/interfaces.d# /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-l2tp-service --debug
nm-l2tp[13017] <debug> nm-l2tp-service (version 1.2.18) starting...
nm-l2tp[13017] <debug>  uses default --bus-name "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp"
nm-l2tp[13017] <info>  ipsec enable flag: yes
** Message: 13:01:51.414: Check port 1701
** Message: 13:01:51.414: Can't bind to port 1701
nm-l2tp[13017] <warn>  L2TP port 1701 is busy, using ephemeral.
connection
        autoconnect : false
        id : 'vpnname'
        interface-name : '--'
        permissions : []
        type : 'vpn'
        uuid : '542b35f3-fadc-4df1-b340-a68eec3a9c3f'

proxy

ipv6
        address-data : []
        dns : []
        dns-search : []
        method : 'auto'
        route-data : []

vpn
        data : {'gateway': '123.456.789.012', 'ipsec-enabled': 'yes', 'ipsec-psk': '0sTiFSU190ZWNobjBsMGczCg==', 'mru': '1400', 'mtu': '1400', 'password-flags': '0', 'refuse-chap': 'yes', 'refuse-mschap': 'yes', 'refuse-pap': 'yes', 'require-mppe': 'yes', 'user': 'vpntest'}
        secrets : {'password': 'vPnt35t'}
        service-type : 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp'

ipv4
        address-data : []
        dns : []
        dns-search : []
        method : 'auto'
        route-data : []

nm-l2tp[13017] <info>  starting ipsec
Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Starting strongSwan 5.9.1 IPsec [starter]...
Loading config setup
Loading conn '542b35f3-fadc-4df1-b340-a68eec3a9c3f'
nm-l2tp[13017] <info>  Spawned ipsec up script with PID 13126.
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA 542b35f3-fadc-4df1-b340-a68eec3a9c3f[1] to 123.456.789.012
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
sending packet: from 111.222.333.444[500] to 123.456.789.012[500] (532 bytes)
received packet: from 123.456.789.012[500] to 111.222.333.444[500] (132 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V ]
received XAuth vendor ID
received DPD vendor ID
received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
selected proposal: IKE:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
sending packet: from 111.222.333.444[500] to 123.456.789.012[500] (244 bytes)
received packet: from 123.456.789.012[500] to 111.222.333.444[500] (244 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH ]
sending packet: from 111.222.333.444[4500] to 123.456.789.012[4500] (68 bytes)
received packet: from 123.456.789.012[500] to 111.222.333.444[500] (68 bytes)
invalid HASH_V1 payload length, decryption failed?
could not decrypt payloads
message parsing failed
ignore malformed INFORMATIONAL request
INFORMATIONAL_V1 request with message ID 1308603116 processing failed
sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 3
sending packet: from 111.222.333.444[4500] to 123.456.789.012[4500] (68 bytes)
received packet: from 123.456.789.012[500] to 111.222.333.444[500] (68 bytes)
invalid HASH_V1 payload length, decryption failed?
could not decrypt payloads
message parsing failed
ignore malformed INFORMATIONAL request
INFORMATIONAL_V1 request with message ID 3696528349 processing failed
nm-l2tp[13017] <warn>  Timeout trying to establish IPsec connection
nm-l2tp[13017] <info>  Terminating ipsec script with PID 13126.
Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
nm-l2tp[13017] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.

(nm-l2tp-service:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:02:04.565: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
```

and in another window:

```
root@client# nmcli c up vpnname
Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown reason
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=542b35f3-fadc-4df1-b340-a68eec3a9c3f + NM_DEVICE=eth0' to get more details.
```

Unfortunately I don't know IPSec well enough, and what I find through google and on this site seems to be several years old and doesn't really match what I see. What do I need to change?

***EDIT***

So, a downvote, but no comment. It would be nice to see why; I haven't simply thrown my question in here because I couldn't be asked to try to solve it myself or carry out a search. Even after some 25 years of Linux development and sysadmin, there are still plenty of things I've never worked with.

There are loads of low-quality 'solutions' to be found, which mention  ipsec, l2tp and other things, usually with pictures of some GUI; but very little that addresses the command line, and most of it seems to be old and irrelevant.

Comment: `Invalid HASH_V1 payload length` is typically a result of Pre-Shared Key Mismatch

Comment: @DouglasKosovic Thank you for commenting. I have actually checked and re-checked everything, but I may of course have missed something; I'll check with more care.